# I set variables inside foreach loop and they are not echoing outside the loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am setting up an array with $key => $value.  I am using this to set up a report from a form submission.  I am trying to set a php variable inside the foreach loop and use it outside the loop; however, it isn't working.  Any ideas why?

```
$formfields = array(
"Company Name" => "company",
"Contact Name" => "name",
"Address" => "address",
"City" => "city",
"State" => "state",
"Zip Code" => "zip",
"Phone Number" => "phone",
"Brand of Tool" => "brand",
"Tool Model" => "model",
"Description of Problem" => "description",
"Repair or Rebuild" => "repairorrebuild",
"Estimate or Repair & Return" => "estimateorrepair"
);



foreach ($formfields as $key => $value) { 
'$'. $value = htmlspecialchars($_POST[$value]); 
}

echo $company .' '. $name;
```

I've tested by echoing the value's inside the foreach loop and they do return the values from the form.  So I know there are no typo's.

Comment: $$value is not the same as '$'.$value. The first refers to a variable names $value and the second is a string $ concatenated to $value.

Comment: Just a quick note here, maybe you could format/indent that last bit of code and make the question more clear. Spread text a little :)

Comment: I reformatted the code.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make dynamic variables you should use `{}`

```
foreach ($formfields as $key => $value) { 
  ${$value} = htmlspecialchars($_POST[$value]); 
}
```

Comment: PERFECT!  Thank you so much.  Doing this was a learning experiment with foreach loops.  But this will allow me to now use this in my application as needed.  I'll accept as soon as it lets me on here.